# Cygwin Diff always returns exit code 57

Tags: cygwin, diff

The diff utility on my Cygwin always returns exit code of 57, no matter if files match, missmatch or do not exist.

I have installed diffutils successfully:

```
$ cygcheck -c diffutils
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
diffutils            3.2-1          OK

$ which diff
/usr/bin/diff
```

Comment: How do you know the exit code is 57? Are you doing `echo $?` immediately after the `diff` command? Show us exactly what you're doing. (BTW, it works fine for me.)

Comment: yes, i'm doing `echo $?` immediately after `diff` command.

Comment: Ok, just to be 100% clear, when you enter this command: `diff /dev/null /dev/null ; echo $?` it prints 57?

Comment: And you don't have `diff` defined as an alias or function (`which` won't detect that)? Assuming you're using bash, what's the output of `type -a diff`?

Comment: below is the output i get `$ type -a diff
diff is /usr/bin/diff
diff is /bin/diff`

Comment: `md5sum /usr/bin/diff` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something must be broken in your Cygwin installation, because the Cygwin version of `diff` doesn't even have code in it to return exit code 57. It only uses 0, 1, and 2. That means some other piece of code is doing the exiting, which is highly suspicious.

I would first try a forced reinstall of `diffutils` and its dependencies, `libintl8` and `libiconv2`. You will find both libraries in the Libs category in Cygwin's `setup.exe`. Click the value in the third column on the "Select Packages" screen until it says "Reinstall". (It should be "Keep" when you first enter this screen. If it's something else, that might be a clue as to what went wrong.)

If that doesn't fix it, I would suspect [BLODA](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.bloda).

Comment: i was not getting Reinstall option. after i installed Diffutils again, its working now. Thanks all for the help.